# how to add a file dependancy in the makefile

Tags: gnu-make

Hi say I have a program called "myProg", it takes one argument which is a file say abc.xml, and generate another file say def.out . So it works like this

myProg -input abc.xml -output def.out

Now, I want to create a makefile to add the dependancy of abc.xml meaning, if the abc.xml is NOT changed, I don't need to call myProg to make def.out . I am just wondering how to achieve this in the makefile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Making a file named `Makefile` something like this should do it:

```
def.out : abc.xml
    myProg -input $< -output $@
```

Beware though that the indent must be done with a tab but I can't put a tab in the code listing here.

The `$<` and `$@` are [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) that will expand to the first prerequisite and the target.

`def.out` would be the default goal as it's the first target so you should just be able to run `make` and get the result you want.

If you want it to rerun if the program is newer than the output you could add it to the prerequisite list like so (assuming `myProg` is in the same directory...):

```
def.out : abc.xm myProg
    myProg -input $< -output $@
```

Comment: @user2167013 I'm glad you're happy with it :) You might like to read here about the stackoverflow etiquette for when you get answers: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers